# unable to send API request to Solana devnet

Tags: networking, firewall, solana, solana-cli, solana-transaction-instruction

I'm doing the following tutorial of creating tokens on Solana.

https://spl.solana.com/token

and it seems that all requests to Solana devnet are failing

```
$spl-token create-token
Creating token 2rxgzZ1tk692aZJXDz8NhTkVXQWB396Z3L21nTUYWCFi
error sending request for url (https://api.devnet.solana.com/): error trying to connect: invalid certificate: UnknownIssuer
```

I'm not so much of an expert when it comes to network, but i thought it was permission issue in firewall as I am currently working on this in corporate environment.

but as I tested with telnet, it doens't seem like a firewall issue
147.28.33.107 is an IP address of Solana devenet network.

```
telnet 147.28.33.107 80
```

Comment: This is likely related to your corporate network.  Currently, from a non-firewalled network, `solana airdrop 1` works when connected to devnet, ie running `solana config set -ud` first.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem but I sorted out by specifying the path to my-keypair.json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).